# AOS.js not animating on slide swipe using Swiper.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, swiper.js, aos.js

I'm using Swiper.js to slide between sections, and also AOS.js to animate on scroll. I want to animate the text within the swipe sections, but only the text within the first section animates and it does it only once when the page is loaded, instead of every time the slide swipes up. I tried many solutions, but none of them worked. Here's what I tried in JS:

1. on slide change, remove AOS classes and call AOS again with AOS.init()
2. on slide change, call AOS with AOS.refresh()
3. on slide change, remove and add AOS classes manually
4. on slide change, add AOS attribute to HTML manually

Here are two snippets that may be edited to work correctly.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  on: {
    init: function() {
      $('.swiper-slide .wrapper').removeClass('aos-init').removeClass('aos-animate');
    },
    slideChange: function() {
      $('.swiper-slide-active .wrapper').addClass('aos-init').addClass('aos-animate');
      AOS.init();
      AOS.refresh();
    }
  }
});
```

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  on: {
    slideChangeTransitionStart: function() {
      $('.swiper-slide .wrapper').hide(0);
      $('.swiper-slide .wrapper').removeClass('aos-init').removeClass('aos-animate');
    },
    slideChangeTransitionEnd: function() {
      $('.swiper-slide .wrapper').show(0);
      AOS.init();
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you will have is the two are not compatible, the swiper doesn't actually scroll the contents using page scroll wherein the AOS uses Intersection Observer to detect the page scroll and if an element is within the view box boundary, the initial animation you see is just the content load init() event, even if you were able to destroy the component which it doesn't support (https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/issues/360)  it would apply to all of the ata-aos elements, so you would see it animated for all the ones in view at the time not just the one in range. You may want to consider changing your approach and look to create a slider with an actual scroll that the Intersection Observer can detect to determine the element being within range or create a function on the swiper to animate the content of the slide yourself. I hope this helps